# Open quickfix in vertical split

Tags: vim-windows, quickfix

If I use the command `:copen` the quickfix buffer will be opened as a horizontal split.

Is there a way (a command) to open it in a vertical split instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prefixing your command with [`:vert`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Avert) modifies it to use a vertical split:

```
:vert copen
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this too, but found out that this does not work for me. Maybe a Vim bug? It just opens a larger horizontal split for me.

Comment: @Akshay Works for me in Vim 7.3.

Comment: Oh, seems to work if I do `vim -Nu NONE`. Nevermind ;). EDIT: Ah it was because I always set the quickfix window to open at the bottom with `wincmd J`